# Must I separate a new disk before installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 alongside windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

[image: c disk, NTFS format]
Must I separate a new disk before installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 alongside Windows 8?

Also, there is only one NTFS disk named C in my computer and Windows 8 is already on it.

Is it possible for me to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 alongside Windows 8 in the same disk C?

That is to say, I don't want to separate a new disk from C.

Comment: @Robin Green I know that answer. I want to make sure I could just follow the install guide without creating a new disk first. I do not state it clear.I will modify it.

Comment: it's not a dupe plz read the question properly.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the question was edited after I flagged it as a dupe

Comment: Do not mix up Windows definition of drive/disk which c: & d: may be partitions but Windows calls them drives. Actually a d: could be another partition in same drive as Windows c: or another physical drive. In Linux a drive is sda, sdb and a physically different device. A partition is a sub-divison of the physical drive and sda1, sda2 etc. You can partition your hard drive and install Linux, but you cannot install Ubuntu inside a NTFS partition if system is UEFI based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible  to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 alongside windows 8 in the same NTFS disk.

Comment: is that means I must seperate a new disk before installation? Or I can just simply follow the guide http://www.ubuntu.org.cn/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

Comment: you have to create a new partition. Ubuntu does not work well on NTFS, anyway.

Comment: follow that guide,and select the option install ubuntu alongside windows.You don't need to manually create a seperate partition for ubuntu,the installer automatically create's that and installs ubuntu on that.